# If $\sum c_{n}4^{n}$ is convergent, is $\sum c_{n} (-4)^{n}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum c_{n}4^{n}$ is convergent.What can be said about the convergence of $\sum c_{n} (-4)^{n}$?

Comment: is $c_n$ positive?

Comment: not mentioned..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very useful theorem on which this question is based.

> **Theorem.** Let $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n$ be a power series centered at $0$.
>
> - If this series converges for $x=d$, then it also converges for all $x$ satisfying $|x|<|d|$.
> - If this series diverges for $x=d$, then it also diverges for all $x$ satisfying $|x|>|d|$.

Note that it says nothing about the case when $|x|=|d|$. And indeed, this borderline case is inconclusive. For example, even when you know that the series converges for $x=d$, it can be convergent or divergent for $x=-d$. Same in case of divergence of the original series. Counterexamples are pretty easy to construct based on the difference between conditionally and absolutely convergent series, such as $\sum(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ versus $\sum(-1)^n\frac{1}{n^2}$.

The utility of this theorem is that from it we can deduce the concept of the *radius of convergence* of a power series. (That's why I'm pretty sure you're currently in the topic of power series in your class.)

Comment: So we can't say anything about given series?

Comment: @omkarGirkar: Yep. You still should convince yourself why this is so by constructing a couple of examples. You have one in the other answer. Now construct another example where the second series converges. See the edit I've just made to my answer about using two series as inspiration.

Comment: Thanks..got it...

Answer (score 0):

Let $c_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{4^nn}$ then $\sum c_{n}4^{n}$ converges while $\sum c_{n}(-4)^{n}$ diverges.

If $c_n$ is the constant $0$ sequence both converge.

Comment: This answer is very misleading -- it seems to imply that the answer is that the other series diverges, which isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: hmm, how does it imply that?

Comment: anyways, I added an example for the other case. I thought it was clear that it is possible for both to converge.

Comment: To an unexperienced reader (such as students as opposed to mathematicians, who already know the stuff), the conclusion of your post (in its original form, first line only) is "diverges". I've learned the hard way to be extra careful when explaining anything to students, because otherwise the message they get often has little to do with the message I intended...

Comment: I don't think extreme spoonfeeding is the way to go, you are just harming the student.

Comment: I agree with you -- I don't like extreme spoonfeeding either! But I am quite a stickler at being clear as to what I mean or what other people mean. :-)